# Compilation problem in Emacs,

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode

I am using Emacs 24.3.1. on Ubuntu.

I am trying use compile in emacs: (`M-x compile`), I choose my Makefile.

It answered me `-*- mode: compilation; default-directory:"path" -*-
Compilation started at Wed Nov  9 10:48:00.` status is `Compilation:run`, I wait, wait and it will never say nothing more. To leave this process I must kill it.

My *Process List*:
compilation     run     *compilation*   /dev/pts/14  /bin/csh -c make -f ../Makefile

When I run it from terminal everything works.

I did one test more I run grep function (`M-x`) `grep -nH all "main" ./*` . It is the same problem. `Grep:run Compiling` but I don’t have any results and a `grep` process is running. To leave this window again I must kill it.

I sure that any packages don’t have impact.

Did someone have similar problem? Can you share how to repair it?

Comment: Welcome to mx.sx! Does the problem appear if you start emacs with `emacs -Q`? Does pressing `C-g` (or maybe spamming it a couple times) allow you to leave the windows without killing them?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer,  I tried it and it doesn't help. I tried do it without my config (~/.emacs) files that why I know that any packages doesn't have impact.

Comment: By `C-c` you mean `M-x`? And what do you mean by "choose my Makefile"?

Comment: Yes M-x, sorry I corrected it.
I choose my Makefile mean: comment make -f ../Makefile
(where ../Makefile is my path)

Comment: It could be csh startup related, Can you clarify in your grep case if you have *both* a `/bin/csh -c grep ...` and a `grep` process, or only the former? Can you move your `~/.cshrc` to a different name and see if that makes and difference? If it does then put the ~/.cshrc back, run the grep again and run `ps axjf` in a different window and look to see what child processes of the csh are running. Welcome to emacs stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solve this problem. I will share the answer.

Before I had problem, I start my shell with `csh` but I would start in `bash`.
So I added line with `bash` in my `.cshrs` to change it automatically each time.

There was big conflict, I don't understand why but I found it based on advice of `@icarus`. Thank you very much.

Finally I edit `etc/passwd` to change it using `chsh` , I found it as better solution.
Compilation works right now, thanks. Good luck.

Comment: Glad it helped. It sounds as if you just had `bash` in your `~/.cshrc` file. You needed a lot more to make this work correctly as you have found out -- set the `SHELL` environment variable, see if you are being run to start a program or interactively and so on.  On stackexchange.com you should mark username like `@icarus` so the user gets notified.